# How to lock an android screen on whilst app running?

Tags: java, android, screen

What should I implement to ensure my screen is always on whilst my app is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wakelock, a documentation on wakelocking can be found in the following link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html